# Background image cover resizing on touch in mobile Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scroll, background-image

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wr7r32ew/

Basically, I have a mobile homepage with an absolutely positioned div with a background image set to `background-size: cover` and a footer below it.

When you scroll in mobile Chrome only, the background-image will zoom in/zoom out slightly upon touch (I do not want this). This issue is only present in Chrome in both iOS and android, and not observed in Safari or native Android.